# Apache deja de responder y no se soluciona tras reinciar

Tags: ubuntu, apache, apache2

tengo un problema con un apache (2.4.29) sobre Ubuntu 18.04.4 en un VPS, lo explico un poco:

en su momento, terminé de configurarlo todo, con varios vhosts, casi todos levantando webs en WordPress, y todo funcionaba a la perfección. O no: a los pocos días me doy cuenta de que las webs han dejado de responder. Ninguna de las webs tienen demasiado tráfico, pero como en ese momento no podía dedicarle mucho tiempo, reinicié y todo solucionado. Al poco tiempo vuelve a suceder lo mismo.

Entonces instalé monit para hacer un poco el seguimiento a todo y reiniciar los servicios si fuera necesario. Pero esto no me solucionó nada. Indagando un poco más he detectado el siguiente comportamiento:

- Reinicio el sistema: todo funciona correctamente
- Al cabo de unas horas ¿2? ¿5? las webs dejan de responder, pero sí me responde a host que apunta a la página por defecto de Apache.
- Si reinicio Apache el problema no se soluciona, necesito reiniciar el sistema para que todo vuelva a la normalidad.

¿Qué comprobaciones podría realizar para llegar al origen del problema?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Cuánta RAM y CPU tiene el VPS?

Comment: 1 Core (desde 2GHz) y 2GB RAM, lo tengo con OVH

Comment: Quizás necesites mejor hardware. Por otro lado, tu pregunta encaja mejor en https://serverfault.com/ dado que es un sitio enfocado en temas de servidores

Comment: Gracias, pasaré a comentarlo allí.

Por concluir un poco en este hilo, en el último reinicio que he hecho he parado el monit (pensaba que ya lo había desactivado anteriormente pero no) y parece que ahora, con un solo vhosts levantado, el apache sigue vivo con normalidad, así que diría que Monit era una parte del problema. Iré probando a levantar uno por uno y quizás eso me termine llevando efectivamente a qué necesito más recursos para cierto número de sitios.